# Xamarin Forms iOS TitleBarTextColor not changing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

To change the TitleBarTextColor so far I tried a lot and my code now does change the back button color and the area on the very top of the screen, but the title!

in my AppDelegate FinishedLaunching function (it's after Forms.Init() and before LoadApplication()):

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes
{
    TextColor = UIColor.White
});
```

In my ViewModel:

```
(App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#990000");
(App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).BarTextColor = Color.White;
```

And this is how I'm navigating between the pages (not all the pages):

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://wwww.x.com/NavigationPage/TabbedNavigationPage?selectedTab=XPage/Document", UriKind.Absolute));
```

I even try to call the ViewModel code after the Prism navigation but it doesn't work... I'm a beginner and don't fully comprehend Prism and or Xamarin Forms.

[EDIT] -> I also tried to create a new class and inherit it from `NavigationPage`, set the `BarTextColor` in its constructor and use that class in the navigation like this: `await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://wwww.x.com/NEWCLASSCREATED/TabbedNavigationPage?selectedTab=XPage/Document", UriKind.Absolute));` But, as you may know, it is still not working.

Here's a Image ;)

[imageToSeeThatImNotLying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyPPF.png)

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Is your App MainPage actually wrapped in a navigation page? If so in your `App.xaml` when you create your navigation page you can do it there. For example, `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#990000"), BarTextColor = Color.White };` that should set it and you shouldn't need to do anything in the `AppDelegate` at all.

Comment: @Nick, I tried that in my App.xaml.cs and it couldn't find the MainPage class/type... I puted the code in the OnInitialized function.

Comment: replace `new MainPage()` with whatever your initial page class is

Comment: @Nick I finnaly been able to try It, but it's still not working :( ... I placed the code in my App.xaml.cs and said that LoginPage is the one with the textcolor in white... but to go to the page with the actual title is: Login -> Another page -> Page with title... I believe it's not working because I'm setting it only for LoginPage, so could you guide me to set it to the "Page with title"? I'm not being able to put your code in the code behing or ViewModel of that page...

Comment: Or hel me to set it for the entire project if possible?

Comment: It should work for all pages unless you have multiple navigation pages, which you should typically only have one. Also, without more code to see like from your pages/how you're navigating between them, it's hard to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Nick I edited the question details, please tell me if that's what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finnaly managed to work this out...

What I had to do was to create a custom `Content Page` because all the other solutions wasn't working. So I created this custom renderer only in my iOS project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(CustomContentPageRenderer))]
namespace TestProject.iOS.Bll.Utils.Renderers
{
    public class CustomContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void DidMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
        {
            base.WillMoveToParentViewController(parent);

            var titleView = new UITextView();
            var page = this.Element as ContentPage;

            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(page.Title))
                {
                    titleView.Text = page.Title;
                    titleView.TextColor = UIColor.White;
                    titleView.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(17, UIFontWeight.Regular);

                    var bgColor = page.BackgroundColor;
                    titleView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA((int)bgColor.R, (int)bgColor.G, (int)bgColor.B, 0);
                    parent.NavigationItem.TitleView = titleView;
                    parent.NavigationItem.TitleView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I also removed all the code that I puted before in my `AppDelegate` file and in the `App.xaml.cs` file as well. I left the codes from the `ViewModels` because it was changing the back button to white, and I deleted the new `NagivationPage` class that I created before.

I'm going to explain why I did some of the things that you saw there:

To change the Title I created a `UITextView()` and set it to my `NavigationItem.TitleView` of the parent page. I set `titleView.Text = page.Title;` because my original page already have a title, so I'm just reusing it. And the `backgroundcolor` I had to do all of that so the `backgroundcolor` property works just in the way that I wanted.

And this `DidMoveToParentViewController` function was just so it can do all that before `NavigationAsync` from Prism.